# Calculate distance between words in a window in Python

Tags: python, matrix, distance, text-mining

I want to build a distance matrix (sparse matrix), which is similar with co-occurrence matrix. In a window of size 7, I want to compute the distance between two specific words and move the window by turn.

Take this for example:

> anarchism/NOUN NIL NIL NIL term/NOUN NIL abuse/NOUN NIL NIL NIL NIL working/NOUN class/NOUN radicals/NOUN

This is what I have noun, I replace non-related words with "NIL" (just indicates the distance) and preserve the nouns and adjectives.

I want to compute the distance between (term, abuse), (working, class), (working, radicals), (class, radicals). Other distances are not computed because they are out of window size 7.

And I want to get a matrix-record for sparseMatrix such like this:

```
    i       j     dis
1 term    abuse    2
2 working class    1
3 working radicals 2
4 class   radicals 1
```

---

Is there some efficient way to do this in Python, my corpus size could be 10G+.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot understand what you want. Could you explain more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to get distances of 7 or less. You can do this easily by this process (pseudocode):

```
for each word index:
  skip if word[index] is NIL
  for offset from 1 to 7:
    stop if index+offset is past last element
    skip if word[index+offset] is NIL
    make triplet (word[index], word[index+offset], offset)
```

It should be easy stuffing it into [scipy sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) (you will also need to assign each discrete word an ID, as scipy matrix indices must be integers).

EDIT: No idea why I put `6` in there... Should be `7`, of course.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this. Sorry for probable misunderstanding. What does "stop if index+offset is past last element" mean? And also, I think it is a O(n^2) algorithm, right? Could we speed up?

Comment: I mean, you don't want `word[index+offset]` to give you an exception, so you break the inner loop. And it is not O(n^2), it is O(7n), which same as O(n).

Comment: Thank you @Amadan! I've done it! also transform the sparse matrix using scipy.